# cakephp render + afterfilter variables are unset

Tags: cakephp, variables, render, cakephp-2.1

I am trying to use render for specific action names in my app.
Actually, here are my condition set in my AppController::afterFilter()

```
    if($this->action == 'parameter') {
        $this->render('/Elements/parameter');
    }
    else if($this->action == 'datagrid') {
        $this->render('/Elements/datagrid');
    }
```

And in my controller `/samples/parameter` :

```
            $this->set('model', Inflector::singularize(Inflector::camelize($this->name)));
        $this->set('controller', $this->name);
        if($parameter_id) {
            $this->set('mode', $mode);
            $this->set('parameter', $this->Sample->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Sample.id' => $parameter_id))));
        } else {
            $this->set('mode', 'add');
            $this->set('parameter', array());
        }
```

I know that I have to render AFTER the definition of variables, so I use `afterFilter` Something I don't understand or missed ?

**Infos:**
I have set in `Samples Controller` the function

```
    public function afterFilter(){
        parent::afterFilter();
    }
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `afterFilter()` callback is called **after** rendering process is done, so calling `render()` inside it is doing it wrong.

If you want to change the view to be rendered do so in `beforeRender()`. So do something like

```
if ($this->action == 'parameter') {
    $this->view = '/Elements/parameter';
} elseif ($this->action == 'datagrid') {
    $this->view = '/Elements/datagrid';
}
```